# How do I access a node.js script through a web browser?

Tags: node.js, less

I'm trying to use [lesscss](http://lesscss.org/) server side. It requires node.js for that, I've installed it and looked at some tutorials but now I have no idea how to use it. After you create a server/tcp or whatever how to you get to it from your website?

I wanna be able to do like mywebsite.com/css and when I go there it'll output the css that node.js tells it to.

Comment: What webserver are you using?

Comment: If apache is a webserver then apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this solution:
http://arguments.callee.info/2010/04/20/running-apache-and-node-js-together/